# OPE in a general $d$-dimensional CFT

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

I am looking for a good reference which explains how to express an OPE in a general $d$-dimensional CFT for bosonic and fermionic fields. Precisely, I don't understand the reason of the appearance of higher spin operators in a scalar-scalar OPE, and why only symmetric traceless operators.

Also if I could get some reference for fermionic fields, it would be great.

Comment: I'm guessing you will have found your references by now. But your subquestion: "why only symmetric traceless operators" is answered in this post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/316765/130040

Comment: But what about fermionic fields ?